# using sstream header file in C++

Tags: c++, sstream

so I was trying to utilise the istringstream to parse through a text file. The idea is to break down each line by space and based on the substring do stuff. The code works fine except for two things, it double counts last substring for each line and it seg faults when its done reading through the file. I have not used sstream before so any insight would be helpful.

```
file.getline(str,80);

    while(!file.eof())

    {

        cout<<str<<endl;
        istringstream iss(str);
        while (iss)
            {
                iss >> sstr;
                cout << "Substring: " <<sstr << endl;
         }
        file.getline(str,80);   
    }
```

Comment: I would highly encourage changing from `file.getline(str, 80);` to `std::getline(file, str);` ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/ ), assuming `str` is a `std::string`.  At the very least, you don't have to worry about lines that are "too long."

Comment: Thanks a ton guys....works like a charm. I used the getline as the first while loop condition and iss>>sstr as the second while loop condition.

Comment: I would also highly encourage changing from `while(!file.eof())` to `while(file)` which will also stop on stream errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `while` loops should go like this:

```
std::string line;

while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    std::string token;

    while (iss >> token)
    {
        cout << "Substring: " << token << endl;
    }
}
```

The `getline` and input operations return the stream object, which itself has a specialized conversion to bool that indicates whether the operation succeeded, and it will fail precisely when you've reached the end of the respective stream.

Answer (score 2):

[`while !eof` is almost always wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.5).

Switch to a different C++ book, and tell us which one you're using now so that we may mock and warn accordingly.

```
while (file.getline(str,80)) {
    cout<<str<<endl;
    istringstream iss(str);
    while (iss >> sstr) {
       cout << "Substring: " <<sstr << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, the member-`getline` is a bit clunky for my taste... as is the magic `80`.

Comment: @Kerrek: Indeed, global `getline` would be better. But I'm just fixing _one_ error here. :)

Comment: I have seen !eof() in a ton of books. Could you point me to as to why its a bd idea?

nvm found it...thanks!!

Comment: @Tomalak: Yeah, usually one error at a time is the Right Way. But this time I tried to measure carefully what the OP wanted and what I thought he needed and took a shot... it's thin ice, though -- other times that sort of liberty gets you downvoted :-)